# iOS app development in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible that ,without using a Mac OS X and XCode, one can create apps for iOS using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 7 system ? If yes, then is Swift or Coca Touch available for Visual Studio or can I make do with C# while writing code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of do this with [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com), as well as building Android applications. You still need to *have* a Mac in order to build iOS/Mac OS X applications, but you don't need to interact with it directly - it just needs to be on the network in order to complete the build the app, for licensing reasons. On the other hand, to run/debug the app, you'll either need a device plugged into your Mac, or run the emulator on your Mac. (Personally I have a Mac Mini for this purpose, and it's on my KVM... so I don't use it directly very often, but it's available when I need it.)

This is *not* building code in Swift or Objective-C - it's using C# which is then ahead-of-time compiled into native code. The Cocoa Touch libraries are exposed to your C# code so you're still using the same widgets etc... you're just building in C#.

Comment: Will a VM with an ISO image of Mavericks OS X do ? Will i be able to download XCode there and test my code ?

Comment: @SandySands: I honestly don't know - I have no experience of running Mac OS X in a VM. I would seriously consider getting a Mac Mini though... less portable than a VM, of course, but potentially simpler in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you can't do iOS development without Mac OS X and xCode.

However if you want to develop iOS apps in c# then you can use [Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/) but keep in mind you will need a mac with xCode connected in your network to build the code.

Comment: Will a VM with an ISO image of Mavericks OS X do ? Will i be able to download XCode there and test my code ?